# jquery slider - move slider on text input

Tags: jquery

just trying to make a nice slider with jquery
the slider happily changes the input - but I'd like the user to be able to enter a number and the slider moves to that value a short pause after they stop typing...
the slider does that (currently after committing the value)- but the input doesn't move - it's delayed and moves to the 'old' position

example here:
http://free-cursor.org/dev/slider.php

```
    $(function(){           
        $('#slider_x').slider({
            animate: true,
            step: 1,
            min: 300,
            orientation: 'horizontal',
            max: 1000,
            start: function(event, ui){
                $('input[id=current_value_x]').empty();
                slide_int_x = setInterval(update_slider, 10);   
            },
            slide: function(event, ui){
                setTimeout(update_slider, 10);  
            },
            stop: function(event, ui){
                clearInterval(slide_int_x);
                slide_int_x = null;
            }
        }); 

    });
    function update_slider(){
        var offset = $('.ui-slider-handle').offset();
        var value = $('#slider_x').slider('option', 'value');
        $('input[id=current_value_x]').val(value).css({left:offset.left });
        $('input[id=current_value_x]').fadeIn();
    }
    function update_slider_y(){
        var offset = $('.ui-slider-handle').offset();
        var value = $('#slider_y').slider('option', 'value');
        $('input[id=current_value_y]').val(value).css({left:offset.left });
        $('input[id=current_value_y]').fadeIn();
    }
```

Comment: For linking us to demonstrations of your code, you're better off using [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar, where we can see, and experiment with, the code as well as the result and see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this will solve your problem,

http://jsfiddle.net/Yn883/2/

You have to wait for the slider position left "ui-slider-handle" value to update. So i have used setTimeout function.

```
$('input[id=current_value_x]').change(function () {
                var value = this.value;

                $("#slider_x").slider("value", value);
                // now move the input 
                setTimeout(function(){update_slider()},500);
            });

function update_slider(){
        var position = $('.ui-slider-handle').position();
        var value = $('#slider_x').slider('option', 'value');
        $('input[id=current_value_x]').val(value).css({left:position.left });
        $('input[id=current_value_x]').fadeIn();
    }
```